# Creating bitbucket repository using Git bash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to create a bitbucket repository through git bash and I am suing Curl command as below:

```
$ curl -k -X POST -v -u username:xxxxx -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://bitbucket.org.local/projects/proj1/repos/repotest \
  -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks" }'
```

Upon running this command, I am getting invalid credential error and the output looks like below:
[image]

My credentials are correct but I am unable to create the repository. Any help?!!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using bitbucket-cli.

First, install it using pip

```
pip install bitbucket-cli
```

Then create a repo using

```
bitbucket create --private --protocol ssh --scm git YOUR_REPO_NAME
```

Note that this creates a private git repo, you can use --public for public access and --scm hg if you use Mercurial. Username argument can be added via --username YOUR_USER_NAME.

Comment: Do I need to install python to install pip?

Answer (score 0):

Although pcampana's answer is correct and you could use python and pip, I was checking what could be wrong with the curl command. And I guess you are missing the rest path in the url and the name of the repository should be in the post data. (https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.3.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp152)

I guess, the missing `rest/api/1.0` in the url makes the server think that you want to reach a "normal" webpage for which Basic Authentication seems to not be possible.

So try:

```
curl -k -X POST -v \
    -u username:xxxxx \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://bitbucket.org.local/rest/api/1.0/projects/proj1/repos \
    -d '{"name": "repotest", "scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks" }'
```